# leading space with regex match

Tags: regex, vba

A newbie to regex, I'm trying to skip the first set of brackets `[word1]`, and match any remaining text bracketed with the open bracket and closing brace `[...}`

Text: `[word1] This is a [word2]bk{not2} sentence [word3]bk{not3}`

Pattern: `[^\]]\[.*?\}`

So what I want is to match `[word2]bk{not2}` and `[word3]bk{not3}`, and it works, kind of, but I'm ending up with a leading space on each of the matches.  Been playing with this for a couple of days (and doing a lot of reading), but I'm obviously still missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[[^} ]*}
```

Try this.See demo .

https://regex101.com/r/qJ8qW5/1

Comment: Thanks, that works, now I just need to figure out why.  Still on the steep part of the learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

`[^]]` in your pattern match leading space. That matches any character without `]`.

For example, when text is `[word1] This is a X[word2]bk{not2}`, 
pattern `[^\]]\[.*?\}` matches `X[word2]bk{not2}`.

if any open brackets doesn't appear between `[wordN}` and `{notN}`, you can use:

`\[[^\[}]*}`

Or, you can also use `Submatches` with capturing groups.

```
Sub test()
    Dim objRE As Object
    Dim objMatch As Variant
    Dim objMatches As Object

    Dim strTest As String

    strTest = "[word1] This is a [word2]bk{not2} sentence [word3]bk{not3}"
    Set objRE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With objRE
        .Pattern = "[^\]](\[.*?\})"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set objMatches = objRE.Execute(strTest)
    For Each objMatch In objMatches
        Debug.Print objMatch.Submatches(0)
    Next

    Set objMatch = Nothing
    Set objMatches = Nothing
    Set objRE = Nothing
End Sub
```

In this sample code, pattern has Parentheses for grouping.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation & code, and your solution worked too (still trying to figure out why). Sorry I'm only able to accept one  answer, but I did up the "useful" indicator.